# Likelihood estimation using iid normal samples

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, sufficient-statistics

Given an i.i.d. sample $X = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) \sim N(\mu, 1)$. I have been asked to show that the likelihood of $\mu$ based on the whole sample is proportional to the likelihood based on $\bar{x}$ (the sample mean) alone. I'm a little confused by the phrasing of this question.
I was hoping the perhaps somebody could elaborate on what this question is asking.

Also, as an aside, given a random sample $X = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$, how can one estimate the $\text{Pr(X > x)}$?

Can the MLEs for $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$ be used in normal CDF to estimate $\text{Pr(X > x)}$?

where

$\hat{\mu} = \bar{x} = \frac{\sum_{i}x_{i}}{n}$

and

$\hat{\sigma}^{2} = \frac{\sum_{i}(x_{i}-\hat{\mu})^{2}}{n}$

hence

$\text{Pr}(X > x) = 1 - F(x)$

where $F(x)$ is the CDF evaluated at $x$.

Comment: Write down the *log* likelihood: obviously it is a sum of squares of things. Algebraically attempt to rewrite that in terms of $\bar{x}$; if you're successful, you will see that the likelihood depends on the sample only through the sample mean *and* you will see precisely how it depends on that mean. A little reflection should then indicate how to answer your "aside" question. Your third question, when inverted (given $\alpha$, to find an $x$ for which $\Pr(X\gt x)=\alpha$) is a *tolerance limit*; there are several kinds that cope variously with uncertainties in $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: @whuber his third question is just about the estimate of $\Pr(X>x)$ for a given $x$, I think

Comment: Your comment, @Stéphane, makes me realize there is an ambiguity there.  I had taken the last question to be about the *mean* of $X$, but maybe it's not. If not, it's natural to interpret "$X\gt x$" as being a *conjunction* of events $X_1\gt x_1,X_2\gt x_2,\ldots,X_n\gt x_n$ (which is what such notation means in mathematical communities that deal frequently with complicated sets of inequalities).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent is correct - the third question is about the estimate of $\text{Pr(X>x)}$ for a given $x$. My apologies for the sloppy notation and any ambiguity caused.

Comment: @whuber : After some algebra, through the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem, it can be shown that, in the log likelihood, $\bar{x}$ is a sufficient statistic. Hence, the data ($X$) depends only on $\mu$ through $\bar{x}$ in the following way:

$$\frac{-n}{2\sigma^{2}}(\mu-\bar{x})^{2}$$

where $X \sim N(\mu, 1)$, this is:

$$-\frac{n}{2}(\mu-\bar{x})^{2}$$

However, this only holds if $\text{log} \text{ } L(\mu)$ (log likelihood) is performed after the Fisher-Neyman factorisation algebra. Is this still valid?

Could this be the proportion to the sample mean that has been alluded to?

Comment: You do not apply any theorem to show that the likelihood is proportional to $\exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(\mu-\bar{x})^{2}\right)$ as a function of $\mu$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent : You apply the theorem to show that $\bar{x}$ is a sufficient statistic for the normal distribution, but I'm just wondering if this provides an appropriate answer to my initial question about $\bar{x}$ and its role in determining the likelihood of $\mu$.

Comment: I don't understand you. Your initial question was only to show the factorization.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent : Okay, perhaps I should rephrase.

Firstly, let's take the log likelihood such that:

$$\text{log}L(\mu) = -\frac{n}{2}\text{log}(2\pi\sigma^{2})-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\sum_{i}((x_{i}-\bar{x})-(\mu-\bar{x}))^{2}$$

After some algebra, this becomes:

$$\text{log}L(\mu) = -\frac{n}{2}\text{log}(2\pi\sigma^{2})-\frac{n}{2\sigma^{2}}\sum_{i}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}-\frac{n}{2\sigma^{2}}(\mu-\bar{x})^{2}$$

Can't we, therefore, assert that the third term on the right-hand side is the degree to which the likelihood of $\mu$ is proportional to the sample mean?

Comment: You have written $L(\mu \mid x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \exp\left(-\frac{n}{2}(\mu-\bar{x})^{2}\right) \times \text{"something"}$ with "something" not depending on $\mu$ so that's the answer to your initial question.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent : Thank you; I just wanted to make sure that it was correct.